# Submit an idea to a conference

Tags: conference, presentation, workshop

I was wondering if it is appropriate to submit a work to a conference call, which only presents an idea without further development.

So far, in my field, computer science, I usually submit works following more or less this structure:

- introduction
- background
- methods
- proof of concept
- evaluation
- conclusion

Recently, I have seen a call quite interesting for presenting an idea related to my previous research. For this reason, I have to admit that I know the topic. However, the idea is not implemented, neither I evaluated it. Let's say, the work is only the method.

This scenario makes me doubt about the appropriateness of presenting my idea in the shape of a paper.

Finally, if doing this is not appropriate for a conference. Can it be for a workshop? Or even more, a lighting talk, or a poster?

EDIT ---------------------------------------------------------------------

Apart from the interesting given answers, it is important to note that there are conferences (or tracks) for **position papers**:

*A position paper presents an arguable opinion about an issue. The goal of a position paper is to convince the audience that your opinion is valid and worth listening to, without the need to present completed research work and/or validated results.*

Comment: What is the point of doing this?  Our job as researchers is to flesh out ideas.  This wastes reviewers' time.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus Field peculiarities. "The work is only the method" could be a decent poster in some fields; maybe Bub is originally in that field moving to CS, where conference publications are more important, as Buffy says.

Comment: In CS many conferences have an 'abstracts'  track, where you can submit a 1-2 page abstract detailing the idea and the work you have done so far.  there are doctoral symposiums too, as @Buffy said. Posters would work too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CS, conferences are like journals in other fields: the normal medium to publish fresh results. But it is results. There might be exceptions for some specialized conferences that make exceptions.

Also, many CS conferences have a Workshop track in which unfinished work can be presented and discussed. Likewise, there is sometimes a Doctoral workshop in which PhD students discuss their ongoing research and get feedback.

But for a normal paper track in a typical conference, a completed work will be expected.

Comment: Completed papers itself, they find thousand reasons to reject, submitting this kind of a idea paper is an entertainment for the reviewers.